# Unable to load any usable fontset

Tags: fonts, redhat-enterprise-linux, gvim

I have recently upgraded to VIM 7.4 from 7.3 on system A, and set up a clean install of 7.4 on system B.

When launching gvim on A I get :

```
Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion
Warning: Unable to load any usable fontset
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
E852: The child process failed to start the GUI
```

on system B it works fine.

Both are running `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.7 (Tikanga)`
For both `$LANG` is `en_US.UTF-8`

The installed fonts on both also are the same :

```
/bin/rpm -qa 'xorg*font*' | /bin/sort
xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi-7.1-2.1.el5
xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi-7.1-2.1.el5
xorg-x11-fonts-base-7.1-2.1.el5
xorg-x11-fonts-ISO8859-1-100dpi-7.1-2.1.el5
xorg-x11-fonts-ISO8859-1-75dpi-7.1-2.1.el5
xorg-x11-fonts-misc-7.1-2.1.el5
xorg-x11-fonts-truetype-7.1-2.1.el5
xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.1-2.1.el5
xorg-x11-font-utils-7.1-3
```

What else should I be looking at to find a difference between the two systems? or how do I resolve the issue on system A?

**Update** The issue remains and now seg faults. Updated the error message which is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `xlsfonts` on both systems and compare the output. Perhaps the system A is misconfigured, and installed fonts are not accessible to the applications. If this is the case, you may try

```
xset +fp /path/to/fontdir
xset fp update
```